# Does asking help for troubleshooting a Views query fall under the umbrella of Drupal Answers?

Tags: discussion, questions

Asking for help with creating a View is more or less troubleshooting Views module settings; it is not exactly a question.

For example, I have an existing site in PHP and I wish to convert it to Drupal. It requires translating code into the Views GUI set of options. To post a question would require posting a table of what I'm working with in Views and some description of what I wish to achieve. It is boring, especially since most problems I have with Views are OE.

At its core, it is also a question of code conversion. I have a common user interface pattern, which I already know how to accomplish in HTML & PHP/MySQL, and I need to convert it into a Drupal pattern of modules and module settings. I already know the recipe involves Views and other modules; the results are not the same as the picture.

Then again, I'm stuck; Drupal's forum tends to attract novice users, and my question has languished. Other forums seem to take to Drupal questions differently depending on the time of day, so to speak. So, I'm back here, at Stack Exchange, asking if it is OK to ask a stupid question about Views.

**Bonus:** If it is OK, then how should I post this question? Should I add a screen capture of the Views setting page, the exporting output, or an HTML table of only the settings I used so far?

Answer (score 3):

Questions about Views, which a Drupal module are indeed on-topic on Drupal Answers.

The question should be very specific, and not generic as in "I didn't yet try anything, and I would like to know what you think is the best approach." You should first try to convert the site, and then ask a very specific question about something you are not able to achieve. If all you tried failed without to even get closer to the objective, then you should report what you exactly tried, what the result has been, and why it didn't work.

Every pertinent information is helpful, but the only way to narrow the question is to make some attempts with achieving the task before to ask the question.

Comment: remember "show your work, share your research.." yes.